# How can I sort a list of pointers on c++?

Tags: c++, list, sorting

I must sort a list of pointers like this:

```
list< pair< MyClass*,double> * > * myList
```

myClass code:

```
class MyClass {
    private: 
        int id;
    public: 
        MyClass(int id){ 
            this.id=id;}
        ///...
    }
```

So I must order **myList** to *increasing ID of MyClass*.
***Example***: 
If I have

```
pair<MyClass*,double> * pair1=new pair<MyClass*,double>(new MyClass(1),1.0);
pair<MyClass*,double> * pair2=new pair<MyClass*,double>(new MyClass(2),1.0);
pair<MyClass*,double> * pair3=new pair<MyClass*,double>(new MyClass(3),1.0);
```

and I add, in order pair2, pair3, pair1 to myList, after the sort algorithm
I want pair1,pair2,pair3 in myList.

Can I do it without implement a sort algorithm manually?
Thanks for the answer :D

Comment: `std::sort` would try to sort by pointer, not by ID. You must provide the proper custom `compare` function.

Comment: do you really need all the `*` and `new`s ? I never understood why one would store raw owning pointers in a container, but maybe there is some reason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`std::list::sort()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/sort) can take a custom comparison function. Simply write:

```
myList.sort([](const auto& p1, const auto& p2) {
    return *p1->first < *p2->first;
});
```

This needs `operator<(MyClass, MyClass)` to be defined:

```
class MyClass
{
    /* ... */
    friend bool operator<(MyClass const& lhs, MyClass const& rhs) { return lhs.id < rhs.id; }
 };
```

Comment: `std::sort` requires Random Access Iterators and won't work on a `std::list`. You need to use [`std::list::sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/sort) instead.

Answer (score 5):

Use [`std::list::sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/sort) with a custom binary comparison function similar to:

```
bool cmp(const pair< MyClass*,double> * &a, const pair< MyClass*,double> * &b)
{
    return a->first->getID() < b->first->getID();
}
```

Then:

```
myList.sort(cmp);
```

Comment: You beat me at it ^^ +1

Comment: *" increasing ID"* so `getID() < getID()` instead of `>`.

Comment: `std::sort` requires Random Access Iterators and won't work on a `std::list`. You need to use [`std::list::sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/sort) instead.

Answer (score 0):

That's way too much pointers you have, I must say. Having simply `std::list< std::pair<MyClass,double>> myList;` is perfectly fine and will save you a great deal of headache when the time comes to tracking down and destroying all the objects.

Now, sorting. Sure:

```
#include <algorithmh>

...

class MyClass {
    ...
public:
    int getId() const { return id; }
    ...
};

bool my_compare(const std::pair< MyClass*,double> *& lhs, const std::pair< MyClass*,double> *& rhs) {
    return lhs->first->getId() < rhs->first->getId();
}
```

then call

```
myList->sort(my_compare);
```

Comment: actually i misread your answer... I first thought you provide the solution for no pointers ;)

Comment: `std::sort` requires Random Access Iterators and won't work on a `std::list`. You need to use [`std::list::sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/sort) instead.

Comment: @Blastfurnace Well, and that's how you know the last time I used `std::list` instead of `std::vector` was about 10 years ago.